# Unable to use pip inside jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to create a virtualenv inside jenkins job and then install requirements.txt. But I am unable to create virtualenv. This is what my Jenkins file look like.

```
sh 'sudo easy_install pip; pip install virtualenv'
```

But I am getting

```
+ sudo easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 9.0.1
Processing pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
pip 9.0.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
+ pip install virtualenv
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/test-jenkinsfile@tmp/durable-e0a93859/script.sh: line 3: pip: command not found
```

Comment: either add "/usr/local/bin/" to your path or run it directly: `/usr/local/bin/pip install virtualenv` (make sure that pip is there)

Comment: @Tamar : Thanks . It worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pip command cannot be found within the user's path. the solution is either call it directly from /usr/local/bin/pip or add /usr/local/bin to the user's path

for bash: `PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/bin`

for (t)csh: `setenv PATH "${PATH}:/usr/local/bin"`